# Grade with Floor and Ceiling values

Tags: excel

I have a dataset that looks as follows:

```
+--------+-----+
| TechID | QA  |
+--------+-----+
|    819 | 100 |
|    829 | 100 |
|    831 | 100 |
|    832 |  95 |
|    833 |  94 |
|    839 |  90 |
|    868 |  87 |
|   1013 |  87 |
|   1028 |  84 |
+--------+-----+
```

I'm trying to grade the person (TechID) based on score (QA). Those who have 100 should get 100%, while the person who has 84 should get 0%. I've looked at percentilerank (which gives me the 0) but still gives a fraction less than 100 for the top score.

My latest is `=(COUNTA([TechID]) - RANK.EQ([@QA],[QA],0)) / COUNTA([TechID])` which I will settle for if I have to, but it still doesn't grant 100% to the top performers (only what % of people they did better than).

My eyes are going cross. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, I couldn't figure out how to do the table right. Thanks!

Comment: The problem here is that using the data analysis add-in or the built-in percentile and percentile-rank formulas will only give you 75% for the top three because any single one of them did not trump 100% of everyone else. I suggest writing a workaround formula of sorts (even if it's statistically *abhorrent*). If you simply need to score them with 100 as 100% and 84 as 0%, something like `=(($B$1-$B$9)-(100-B1))/($B$1-$B$9)`, dragged down, should work (assuming your data are in Column A and B). However, word of warning: the equivalent values in that method there decrease really quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With QA data in B2 thru B10, in C2 enter:

```
=100*(B2-MIN(B:B))/(MAX(B:B)-MIN(B:B))
```

and copy down

Comment: This is exactly what my (much more statistically savvy) girlfriend showed me last night. However, she used a secondary table to compute the delta. Your solution is quite elegant!

Comment: This is a typical way to re-scale **any** data...........in our case the re-scale max is 100 and the re-scale min is 0